# Thread that waits for signal

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics

Im making a program that displys points on the screen. each point is processed for some interactions with the other points. and then redraws the points in there new position and starts again. The problem is speed. ive tried to break the prosessing of the list into a number of threads, however the overheads make it slower. ive also tried Parallel.ForEach and it works alot better. however there are still overheads i think can be overcome. So processing the new positions happens in a step method

```
 private void Step ( ) {
    Parallel.ForEach( AllParticles , ( p ) => {  // has overheads :(
        p.Step( ); // compare to other points
     });
     foreach ( Particle p in AllParticles ) {
        p.Finalise( );
        ...
     }
     Draw( );
}
```

Now I could do with something like this

```
 //thread delegate
 void ThreadLoop( ) {
    for ( ; ; ) {
        // Wait for signal . . .
        (int start, int end) signal=WaitForSignal();// get a tuple(int,int)
        //process given work
        for(int idx=signal.start; idx < signal.end;idx++) {
            p[ idx ].Step;
        }
        //set a state to indicate now idle
        // repeate and wait for next signal
    }
 }

 List<Thread> CreateAndStart(int numberofthreads ) { // only needs to create threads and delegates once
     List<Thread> result=new List<Thread>();
     // create and start threads add to list...
     return result;
 }

 void Step(){
     //divide the work into [numberOfThread]s
     //send signal to each thread
     //wait untill each thread is idle
     foreach ( Particle p in AllParticles ){
         p.Finalise( );
           ...
     }
     Draw( );
 }
```

but i cant figure out how to inject the signal and detect when the hreads are waiting. If anybody has an idea of how im suposed to do this properly or if there is a better way to go i would be very gratefull. thank you

Comment: Try to use the ManualResetEvent class.

Comment: @Noisy88 thank you ill take a look into that.